# Howto have a Semantic UI React Dropdown auto-focus when its parent component mounts?

Tags: dropdown, autofocus, semantic-ui-react

I am using [Semantic React UI's Dropdown](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown), and I would like it to have focus as soon as its parent component mounts: the user should be able to search immediately.

I tried using a ref in `render()` of the parent:

```
<Dropdown ref={dd => (this.MyDropdown = dd)}
        ... />
```

...and then calling focus on it in the `componentDidMount` function of the parent component. But the `Dropdown` has no function `focus`, so this method won't work.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // I want to do something like the next line here, but 'focus' is not available on the component.
    //this.MyDropdown.focus();
  }
```

So what should I do instead?

Here is [what I tried so far at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3vlzl4w13q). Note the commented-out line in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Dropdown searchInput={{ autoFocus: true }} />
```

After modification, your code will look like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zkpw1vx1x3)

```
<Dropdown
    ref={dd => (this.MyDropdown = dd)}
    placeholder="Please type something, dude"
    fluid
    search
    selection
    options={options}
    searchInput={{ autoFocus: true }}
  />
```

References:

- [Autofocus of dropdown search field #2108 - GitHub Issues](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2108)

Comment: No,it is not written in official document.